# When to use which with "не" / " нет"

Tags: грамматика, выражения, узус, разница

Why is the word "**не**" used in the phrase:
"**мне не нравится**"= "**I Don't** Like"

But on the contrary "**нет**" is used in this one:
"**у меня нет**"= "I **Don't** Have"

Is it a rule that Always "мне" goes with "не" and "меня" with "нет", I don't find any reasons for the distinction since in English both sentences would include the "I do not" fragment.

Comment: Please stop attaching completely unrelated images to the posts.

Comment: @dimitry I will continue doing it as I find suitable for my questions and posts, since is in my very own rights to do it. As long as I am not posting any sort of violent, sexually explicit or graphic content in any way. There is no argument for intercepting on an image that DOES INDEED RELATE TO RUSSIAN CULTURE. I am not directly attacking or offending anyone, if you don't think it is "professional" then leave the community, this is a free forum platform for self expression. So really buddy, go an X urself if you think you can interfere with my means of expression.

Comment: if only he knew what RUSSIAN CULTURE really is, i mean it's best and valuable part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a fairly novice speaker but I think I can explain this well enough. Usually "не" is used to negate a verb, for example: "Я *не* хочу..." -> " I *do NOT* want...

In the second construction you used, нет still means no. Although the English equivalent of "У меня нет..." is "I don't have...", grammatically it is closer to "At me, there is/are no...". So while non-native Russian speakers will think of нет as "do not" in this scenario, it still means "no".

Comment: Thanks a lot brother seems that we often confuse "У меня " as "I have" but in reality is "At me" so the phrase would literally translate "At me NOT" rather than at me NO" I don't know if I got you right.